# Is Wordpress site_url() function safe to use? ( PhP Security )

Tags: php, wordpress, security

Is the `site_url()` function in wordpress safe or does is have security issues like `$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']` does?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking into the [WordPress code](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/4.8/src/wp-includes/link-template.php#L0), it seems like `site_url` takes info from the WordPress installation's settings, instead of the HTTP header.

So, it *seems* that `site_url` does not have the same security implications as `$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']`  does.

However security is a way too complex subject to address so simply. When coding in WordPress, always use the WordPress functions. If there are any security concerns, the WordPress Core should fix them.

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing your code I don't want to say that it is definitely secure, but all that `site_url()` does it return the URL of your website e.g. `http://www.website.com`. It doesn't return the servers root directory, so I can't see any issues with using that function.

Answer (score 0):

To provide a short answer here: It is a WordPress standard function so I would highly recommend to use it and it is safe to use.

Answer (score 0):

Wordpress uses `$site_url = get_bloginfo('url');` where `get_option()` function return `site_url` that basically use sql query to get value. while

`$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']` variables can be changed by sending a different Host header when accessing the site:

```
curl -H "Host: notyourdomain.com" http://yoursite.com/
```

So `site_url` is safe if there is no sql injection in wordpress.